# Using Reach Router with nested routes fails to parse params

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

With Reach router (not React router!) I have 2 nested routes:

`/g/123`
`/g/123/about`

Where 123 is a `:groupId` parameter:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import GroupPage from "../components/dynamic-pages/group";
import PostsView from "../components/group/views/posts";
import AboutView from "../components/group/views/about";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GroupPage path="/g/:groupId">
        <PostsView path="/" />
        <AboutView path="/about" />
      </GroupPage>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And in the outer `GroupPage` component I need to use the `:groupId` parameter:

```
const GroupPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  debugger;
  const params = useParams();
  const groupId = params.groupId as string;

  // query an API using groupId and store it in a context to be 
  // accessible to other nested components (such as AboutView and PostsView)
```

When I go to `/g/123`, which renders the `PostsView`, it works fine and I receive the `groupId` of 123 inside `GroupPage`, however when I go to `/g/123/about` the `groupId` is lost and `params` is null (still when using `useParams` inside `GroupPage`).

If I move the `useParams` from the `GroupPage` into the nested `AboutView`, then I can receive the `params` and `groupId` from `/g/123/about` but this is frustrating because I don't want to have to repeat the logic for multiple nested components and would rather have it in the outer `GroupPage` component (which needs the `groupId` to query an API for group related data and then I use a context to make it available for those nested components).

Am I doing something wrong and is there a way to achieve what I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that I can use `useMatch` with a wildcard instead to achieve this:

```
const GroupPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  debugger;
  const match = useMatch("/g/:groupId/*");
  const groupId = match?.groupId as string;
```

documentation: https://reach.tech/router/api/useMatch

This always returns the groupId for both the PostsView and AboutView routes.

Unless anyone knows of a better way, we can consider this question resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any params for useParams() for AboutView component since the route does not have any params over there.

You can set the groupId in the context and use it in AboutView

Comment: When I move useParams() into AboutView then it does work though. What you are describing with "You can set the groupId in the context and use it in AboutView" is what I want to do by obtaining the groupId inside of the GroupPage outer component but this does not work.

Comment: I tried rewording it to make it clearer. I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will help you:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import GroupPage from "../components/dynamic-pages/group";
import PostsView from "../components/group/views/posts";
import AboutView from "../components/group/views/about";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GroupPage path="g/:groupId">
        <PostsView path="/" />
      </GroupPage>

      <GroupPage path="g/:groupId/about">
        <AboutView path="/" />
      </GroupPage>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```